Why are Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses considered Christian, but Muslims are not, when they believe the same regarding Jesus, the Trinity, and Bible?
All three believe Jesus is not God, there is no Trinity as understood by traditional Christians, yet at the same time Jesus is the Messiah, the word of God, born of the virgin Mary, and accept the Torah and gospel accounts.
Jesus is the Messiah, and word of God (but Trinity is wrong):
https://quran.com/4/171?translations=95,101,85,20,18,22,19,17

O People of the Book! Do not go to extremes regarding your faith; say nothing about Allah except the truth.1 The Messiah, Jesus, son of Mary, was no more than a messenger of Allah and the fulfilment of His Word through Mary and a spirit ˹created by a command˺ from Him.2 So believe in Allah and His messengers and do not say, “Trinity.” Stop!—for your own good. Allah is only One God. Glory be to Him! He is far above having a son! To Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. And Allah is sufficient as a Trustee of Affairs.

Jesus fulfills the Torah, and brings the gospel:
https://quran.com/en/al-maidah/46

Then in the footsteps of the prophets, We sent Jesus, son of Mary, confirming the Torah revealed before him. And We gave him the Gospel containing guidance and light and confirming what was revealed in the Torah—a guide and a lesson to the God-fearing.

Virgin birth (and immaculate conception?):
https://quran.com/en/at-tahrim/12

˹There is˺ also ˹the example of˺ Mary, the daughter of ’Imrân, who guarded her chastity, so We breathed into her ˹womb˺ through Our angel ˹Gabriel˺.1 She testified to the words of her Lord and His Scriptures, and was one of the ˹sincerely˺ devout.

In the case of Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses, this is sufficient for them to be considered Christians, but in the case of Muslims, they are considered a foreign religion.  What explains this difference in categorization?  A corollary, is there a list of minimal beliefs that categorizes a group as Christian or non-Christian, which would categorize Jesus' disciples as Christian?
In older times, according to John of Damascus, it seems Islam was considered a Christian heresy, not a separate religion.

From that time to the present a false prophet named Mohammed has appeared in their midst. This man, after having chanced upon the Old and New Testaments and likewise, it seems, having conversed with an Arian monk, devised his own heresy.

Based on my limited knowledge of medieval theology, it does seem like Islam (along with Mormonism and Jehovah's Witnesses) would be considered a form of Arianism.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


In the case of Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses, this is sufficient for them to be considered Christians, but in the case of Muslims, they are considered a foreign religion.

First off, this statement is wrong. JWs and LDS are not considered "Christians" by the majority of other groups which call themselves "Christian". The actual difference between JWs, LDS and Muslims is the that former self-identify as "Christian", while the latter don't. That's really all there is to it.

Is there a list of minimal beliefs that categorizes a group as Christian or non-Christian?

This is a much more complex and nuanced question, and agreement on the answer is not going to be universal. However, those groups that subscribe to one or both of the main creeds ("Apostle's", "Nicene") are likely to point to those as a bare minimum, although even there, Orthodox have rather strong feelings about the addition of the Filioque by Roman Catholics and Protestants. The Athanasian Creed is also widely accepted. (Note that Unitarians reject the Nicene and Athanasian Creeds, and are also considered non-Christian by most Nicene Christians.)
Another point, albeit one which is much less clear, is whether a group holds to beliefs that are clearly contradicted by (Protestant) Scripture. LDS and Muslims are certainly excluded on this basis, but even Nicene Christians will argue whether various sects ought to also be excluded. (This is also why I specified Protestant Canon, as various sects include additional content in their Canons. Protestant Canon generally acts as a minimum set accepted by all Christians.)
C. S. Lewis' "Mere Christianity" is also worth a read.
The Nicene Creed isn't a bad starting point, but to rephrase it, I would assert that the points one must agree with to be "Christian" are:

That there exists a supernatural being of maximal goodness (that is, "God") who is responsible for the existence of the Universe as we know it, and of humans in particular.
That God Created humans in a state of perfection, and that humans subsequently disobeyed.
That, as a consequence, all humans are sinful and can only be restored to full communion with God by an act of God.
That God Himself became incarnate in the form of Jesus Christ and subsequently suffered the punishment that us sinners justly deserve.
That the same Jesus Christ subsequently rose from the dead and lives forevermore.
That faith in Jesus' death justifies us before God.

Note, again, that this excludes Unitarians (and JWs, LDS and Muslims). This is because the assertion that Jesus is God has enormous significance in how we understand what happened on the Cross and what it accomplished. This is the most basic message of Christianity, and accordingly, those that significantly alter that core cannot properly be said to be of the same faith.
I've also deliberately omitted one point from the above list:

That the present state of Creation (suffering, disease, decay, death) is a direct result of man's disobedience.

While this is clearly attested in Scripture and has significant theological implications, it also requires that these things did not precede the Fall. Yet scientific evidence clearly shows disease, decay and death happening for as long as we have paleontological evidence. Therefore, either this point is not true, or the Fall happened very close to the beginning of Creation, meaning that humans do not predate any other life by any significant amount of time.
Now... Scripture also asserts that the latter is the case, that humans have been around since day six, and that Creation as a whole (at least in our neighborhood) is only about six thousand years old. Many Christians believe that not only is this scientifically sound, but that many lines of evidence exclude any other interpretation. Others (often committed to rejecting the existence of God, or at least His involvement in any meaningful manner) tell a very different, very incompatible story that many other Christians believe, despite the theological impact thereof. Because they are able to accept both the points of my original list and the incompatible assertions of "science", I don't consider this a "must agree" point.

Would you consider Christians before the Nicene Creed to have been non-Christian, then?

@MichaelW. I think Matthew's point is that it's the set of beliefs written out in Nicene Creed that is important, not the name "Nicene Creed" itself. One can have the same set of beliefs even before Nicene Creed, or even without knowing Nicene Creed.

Did Jesus' disciples believe all the items on your list?

@yters, most likely, yes. Certainly Paul did. The only point that's even potentially problematic is making the leap from the Jewish system of ongoing sacrifice to the understanding that that system could only ever be a stop-gap and that Christ's Sacrifice was necessary. Everything in the list, however, is taught in Scripture and was known since the very early days of the Church.

@MichaelW., what justhalf said. Anyone that believes all of Scripture is Christian. The Nicene Creed is merely a summary of those teachings which, to some extent, picks out those which are most critical. But those teachings existed since the time of the Apostles, even before they were recorded in the Scripture we have today. Thus, "Nicene Christians" existed before the Council of Nicaea happened, they just hadn't acquired that label yet.

The other point worth saying is that Mormons and JWs accept, at least nominally and with caveats, Christian scriptures. Muslims absolutely do not.

@justhalf Apologetics aside, the concept of the trinity was not a belief in first century Christianity, and only appeared in the late second. Claiming that it's been there all along is apologetics and not in sync with historical documentation.

@DJClayworth That's a tricky point, because Muslims will claim they accept Christian scripture, but any verse that contradicts Islamic beliefs will be disregarded as "corrupted". Their Islamic end-times prophecies include finding hidden older copies of the Christian scriptures (similar in concept to the Dead Sea Scrolls) that show their Islamic beliefs are correct, and the Christian beliefs in error. As a Christian, I believe those hidden "true" scriptures would be a falsehood hidden millennia ago by satan to lead believers astray, akin to the fraudulent gospel of Judas.

Oh stop tossing in your personally favorite subject into your answers. The issue of if some things existed before the fall of man or not is outside the scope of the question and detracts from the answer. :(

@MichaelW., the understanding of the Trinity developed over time. But, notice I didn't mention "Trinity" in my list. That Jesus was God incarnate is testified since Thomas' confession mere days after the resurrection, and is also why Jesus was crucified in the first place. It's denial of Jesus' deity that is out of sync with history.

@Wyrsa, and you just go to prove my case, that some people can ignore the theological implications of "if some things existed before the fall of man or not". IMNSHO, those who actively deny those implications are, in fact, not Christian, because their understanding of the nature of sin and atonement is severely at odds with what Scripture teaches. But I choose to believe/hope that it's possible to deny Genesis and still be Christian. (Most Christians don't have a deep understanding of atonement, anyway.)

@Matthew As we have debated at great length, I hold that genesis is not a text book. I agree that sin is why we have suffering on earth. The question is not about genesis unless you make it about it. My comment is purely quality of answer, not "let's debate" your favorite subject here.

@Matthew While it is certainly scriptural to say that the Fall of Man has altered the state of creation, your parenthetical (suffering, disease, decay, death [among non-human animals]) is not--it's an inference which you make but is by no means clear, unequivocal, or uniformly held by historical Christianity. If you think this is a core Christian doctrine you would place St. Augustine, C.S. Lewis (whom you cite), Basil the Great, and others as "borderline" Christians. This is otherwise a perfect answer, but I agree with Wyrsa: You don't need to bring your favorite issue into every post.

@DarkMalthorp, Paul disagrees, not only in Romans 8:20-22, but the entire theology of Christ as the second/last Adam turns into a pretzel, never mind what Genesis-denial says about the character of God. That e.g. Lewis can overlook these issues — that Wyrsa can "agree that sin is why we have suffering on earth" without seeing the gross contradiction — just goes to show what I said, that humans are good at doublethink. The fact remains that denying Genesis has counter-Scriptural theological implications.

@Matthew Did you read the first sentence of my previous comment? While it is certainly scriptural to say that the Fall of Man has altered the state of creation, your parenthetical (suffering, disease, decay, death [among non-human animals]) is not--it's an inference which you make but is by no means clear, unequivocal, or uniformly held by historical Christianity.

@DarkMalthorp, did you read Romans 8? Do you say that God's "Very Good" Creation is one which was subjected to "futility" and "bondage to corruption"? Was that Creation flawed, in need of a do-over? Because that is what you must insist if you reject Genesis. And that is not a theologically neutral claim. Whether there is uniform agreement on this point is irrelevant; I've said repeatedly that I believe/hope Faith can exist despite holding ideas contrary to Scripture. As to clarity, it is perfectly clear to those who do not refuse to see.

@Matthew Sure, it's not theologically "neutral" - I doubt any claim is. But interpreting "futility" and "bondage to corruption" as necessarily meaning "suffering, disease, decay, death"--that goes beyond what is written and is squarely in the realm of "inference". Given that so many respected theologians and philosophers, including some whom you respect, disagree with your interpretation here, perhaps some introspection is warranted on your part.

@DarkMalthorp, "it's not theologically 'neutral'", good, then we agree. What we disagree about seems to be how important it is. I maintain that its importance is non-negligible. You've noted your disagreement. Need we continue to belabor the disagreement in comments? (Admittedly, I'm curious now what meaning you would ascribe to Romans 8, but chat would be a better venue.)

I have to agree that the last section of this answer is irrelevant to the question and it really detracts from what was said before that. The answer would be greatly improved if the "deliberately omitted" point were in fact omitted. (If I didn't already have an answer of my own here, I'd downvote this answer based on the presence of that section, not necessarily because I disagree with it, but simply because it doesn't belong there.)

It is unclear to me if you are proposing that CS Lewis agrees with the list/arguments you've provided. His name is preceded & followed by positions he did not argue in Mere Christianity or, to my knowledge, in any of his other published works. Can you clarify?


Why are Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses considered Christian, but Muslims are not …?
All three believe Jesus is not God, there is no Trinity as understood by traditional Christians, yet at the same time Jesus is the Messiah, the word of God, born of the virgin Mary, and accept the Torah and gospel accounts.

But those beliefs are all secondary to the primary belief of Christianity.
John 3:16-17 (NKJV) states:

16 “For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son, that whoever believes in Him should not perish but have everlasting life.
17 “For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but that the world through Him might be saved.

It's very difficult to consider any denomination as Christian if they don't accept that crucial belief.

Muslims do not believe this doctrine and would consider it blasphemous.
(They deny Christianity's central tenet.)
Islam teaches that a different person was substituted for Jesus so that the real Jesus could later appear to have been resurrected.
(They deny the very means by which salvation is paid for.)
Islam claims that it supersedes both Judaism and Christianity.
(They deny Christianity itself.)

There is no reason for anyone, including Muslims, to consider Islam to be a Christian faith.

They consider God having a son to be blasphemous, although they don't mean the same thing that Christians mean by that phrase.  From what I see in the Quran, they seem to take sonship in a literal physical sense, that Christians believe God the Father, Mary, and Jesus are all gods, and that God the Father impregnated Mary to create a son.  They don't mean the Nicene creed statement that Jesus is "begotten not made".  They do sort of think that the world is saved through Jesus being a prophet and bringing a special gospel teaching.

@yters, there are many variations within Christianity (e.g. Jesus is/is-not God, the Godhead has one/two/three members, Jesus was-created/always-existed, unrepentant sinners receive eternal-torture/eternal-unconsciousness, etc.) but the central Christian belief that all denominations hold and which makes it different from all other religions is that the only way anyone can be saved is through using Jesus's execution to pay one's debt to God. Muslims do not see Jesus in that way.

I don't think that precise formulation is universal among all denominations.  For instance, the Eastern Orthodox have a different understanding of how Jesus saves us from our sin, since they don't believe in original sin.  And others believe people can't owe God anything, since God is entirely self sufficient and can never be lacking in anything.  The Catholic view is that man's fundamental problem is his soul's love is disordered, and Jesus' sacrifice reunites our love with God.

And looking over at the Islam stack exchange, it actually seems their view of Jesus, based on interpretation, is more compatible with Christianity than it seems at first glance.  For instance, regarding the sense in which a muslim could in fact say Jesus is God's son in a metaphorical manner similar to Christian usage: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/can-muslims-consider-isa-the-spiritual-son-of-god?rq=1

@yters Since Muslims do not recognize original sin, they see no need for salvation in the Christian sense. There is nothing to be saved from. Consequently, if there was no original sin, there is no need for a Savior. Salvation, in Islam, is based upon the deeds of a person.

@Kristopher says "if there was no original sin, there is no need for a Savior" — many Christians do not believe in the doctrine of original sin, where everyone inherits Adam and Eve's guilt. Yet they still believe that it is possible for individuals to sin, so there is still need for a Saviour.

@RayButterworth not according to Muslims. Which is a reason  they are not considered Christian

Muslims believe that Christ DID NOT die on the cross. They believe that a substitution was made and that another died in his place. || — Quran 4:157–158[12] says 'That they (The Jews) said (in boast), "We killed Christ Jesus the son of Mary, the Messenger of Allah"; but they killed him not, nor crucified him, but so it was made to appear to them, and those who differ therein are full of doubts, with no (certain) knowledge, but only conjecture to follow, for of a surety they killed him not.
Nay, Allah raised him up unto Himself; and Allah is Exalted in Power, Wise.'


Jehovah's Witnesses and Mormons have accepted and believed that Jesus is the Son of God while Muslims have rejected that belief with the reasoning behind that being ~ God cannot have a son

The Jehovah's Witnesses and the Mormons have accepted the message from the gospels that Jesus suffered in the hands of sinners, died and rose on the third day while Muslims believe that Jesus was not arrested, neither did he die but hold onto the belief that God saved him from the hands of the chief priests and the Romans


The two beliefs above are central to Christianity and their rejection is what disqualifies Muslims from being considered Christian.

This is a pretty good answer, although Muslims do believe Jesus was at least created in a special way unlike any other human.  I also don't know if JW quite believe in Jesus being the actual son of God, or a special creation like the Muslims believe.

@yters, yes Muslims believe the conception of Jesus was immaculate or special but they  rejected the teachings above that Jesus is God's begotten son and that he died and rose from the dead.

Others have addressed the claim that Jehovah's Witnesses and Mormons "are considered Christian". Most have rejected the claim for both parties. I may address these issues in a separate answer, but it seems useful to provide a firm foundation for the differences between Islam and Christianity.
The following deals with one utterly foundational difference between Islamic and Christian beliefs. There are others.
Muslims believe that Christ DID NOT die on the cross. They believe that a substitution was made and that another died in his place.
The death (and resurrection) of Christ as a sacrifice for sin is the foundation of Christianity.
(eg 1 Corinthians 15:12-32)

Quran 4:157–158[12] says (i)


'They (The Jews) said (in boast), "We killed Christ Jesus the son of Mary, the Messenger of Allah"; but they killed him not, nor crucified him, but so it was made to appear to them, and those who differ therein are full of doubts, with no (certain) knowledge, but only conjecture to follow, for of a surety they killed him not.
Nay, Allah raised him up unto Himself; and Allah is Exalted in Power, Wise.'

(i) From Wikipedia Islamic views on Jesus's death <-- much more detail provided.
Wikipedia is quoting from The Crucifixion and the Qur'an: A Study in the History of Muslim Thought text not provided.

This page is useful in that it provides extensive detail of the basis for the claims regarding Muslim beliefs and then the writer goes to very substantial lengths to demolish the arguments and to reconcile Muslim and Christian beliefs. I personally feel that "he is straining at gnats" AND that the lady doth protest too much AND ... , but others may be persuaded by his arguments. Although, I can't imagine why :-).

“It Was Made to Appear Like that to Them:” Islam’s Denial of Jesus’ Crucifixion
Gregory R. Lanier, Assistant Professor of New Testament, Reformed Theological Seminary, Orlando
From the above, 3 translations of Sura 4:157-158

Haleem—[Jews] said, ‘We have killed the Messiah, Jesus, son of Mary, the Messenger of God.’ (They did not kill him, nor did they crucify him, though it was made to appear like that to them; those that disagreed about him are full of doubt, with no knowledge to follow, only supposition: they certainly did not kill him.)

Sahih International—And for their saying, ‘Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah.’ And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but another was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain.

Yusuf Ali—That they said (in boast), ‘We killed Christ Jesus the son of Mary, the Messenger of Allah’; – but they killed him not, nor crucified him, but so it was made to appear to them, and those who differ therein are full of doubts, with no (certain) knowledge, but only conjecture to follow, for of a surety they killed him not.



MORMONISM / Church of Jesus Christ of the latter day saints / LDS Church
I will use "LDS" as an abbreviation for the group's official name.
This Quora thread contains many responses from LDS members who describe and defend their beliefs.
The commenters are presumably largely not church experts or authorised to speak formally on behalf of their church but reading through the 30 or so pages a very consistent and clear statement of beliefs emerges.
Their are many references which provide a more formalised description of LDS beliefs, but in the above references thread you'll find a very clear statemenmt of relevant beliefs.
I do not wish to comment on the validity of individual beliefs but can clearly state that
- the beliefs described by numerous people with substantial overlap are incompatible with core Christian beliefs in a very large number of areas.
In "core Christian" I would include the common beliefs of
i  Protestant, Roman Catholic, Orthodox,
ii and in large part both Seventh Day Adventist and Jehova witness churches.
Despite the significant differences in some areas between each of the above, they share a commonality of belief in the core role and person of Christ which the LDS Church in no way shares.
While not all the above groups hold trinitarian beliefs, and the JW church has "dangerously different" areas of belief, the LDS church shares essentially no commonality of understanding of Christ or the Father. Nor of the relationships of mankind/angels/demons, nor of the relationship of Christ to mankind, or to The Father, or to Satan. In just about every conceivable way their core beliefs are different from those of core Chistianity. Statements such as "we believe that Christ is a god" need extremely careful attention. We share the same words, but not the same meanings.
Does this make them wrong per se?
They will of course say 'no'.
Does this make them non-Christian as the term is understood by essentially all other Christians.
Yes.  Definitely.

If anyone is interested, I expanded all the "read more" parts of that Quora thread and saved it as a PDF. You could do the same - or ask me for a copy. (email addrerss in my profile).(Yes, 'spam' is a legitimate part of the address. Please include LDS in the subject line.

At last! Conclusive evidence that Islam is NOT Christian. They deny that Jesus died, nor was he resurrected, which is foundational to Christianity.

It's a long time since I saw a question so guaranteed to stir up a spiritual hornet's nest as this! You no doubt did not intend to do that, but those who know the religious beliefs of all three groups you mention can only shake their heads in wonderment.
There's no need for me to say anything about what each group would object to with the assumptions made. They will likely pile in before long.
This answer is very simple: the only worth-while opinion as to whether anybody is a Christian or not, is that of the Lord Jesus Christ himself. Those who belong to him by faith have been saved from their sin, and everlasting life has already started with their spiritual new birth. They have no need to try to prove that to anybody. They just live in the light and love of their only Saviour, seeking daily to be more like him. Other people sense something different, even if they cannot put their finger on it; the indwelling spirit of Christ.
As for the opinions of people as to those three groups being Christian, or not... they can think as they like, but given what Jesus said in the Bible about what following him entails, that is enough to see whether those three groups are following Jesus only, or a new religion that was started long after Jesus had returned to heaven.

I was ready to upvote your answer as the only valid answer in the list... until I read your last paragraph, which made a lie of everything you previously said. Judge not lest by that judgement ye be judged.

@JBH  I can fully understand why a supporter of the Latter Day Saints religion would take offense at my last paragraph. I pray you will, one day, come to understand that it is Christ who judges, and that pointing to Christ (and not to any religion) is what matters.

I believe wholeheartedly that Christ will judge. What I don't believe is that you're Jesus Christ. Should you care to delete your last paragraph (the one that assumes the role of Jesus and judges), I'll upvote, delete my comments, and leave a comment thanking you for teaching true doctrine.

To find the answer to this question, we need to define what is a "Christian". Biblically speaking, we see the first use of the word at Acts 11:26 (KJV) "... And the disciples were called Christians first in Antioch."
Note Strong's definition:

Word Origin: Derived from Χριστός (Christos), meaning "Christ" or "Anointed One," with the suffix -ιανός (-ianos), indicating belonging to or a follower of.
...
Usage: The term "Christianos" refers to a follower of Christ, specifically those who adhere to the teachings and lifestyle of Jesus Christ. It denotes an individual who identifies with the beliefs and practices of Christianity, acknowledging Jesus as the Messiah and Savior.
Cultural and Historical Background: The term "Christianos" was first used in Antioch, as recorded in the New Testament, to describe the disciples of Jesus (Acts 11:26). Initially, it may have been used by outsiders as a label for the followers of Jesus, possibly with a derogatory connotation. Over time, however, believers embraced the term as a badge of honor, signifying their allegiance to Christ. The early Christians were distinct in their monotheistic worship, ethical teachings, and communal lifestyle, which set them apart from the surrounding Greco-Roman culture.

How are Mormons (Latter-day Saints) considered “Christian”?

What Latter-day Saints Believe
Jesus Christ plays a central role in our beliefs and in our lives. Our mission is to invite all of God’s children to follow Jesus and experience the joy that is possible because of Him.
(Source: The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints—About Us)

How are Jehovah’s Witnesses considered “Christian”?

Yes. We are Christians for the following reasons:

We try to follow closely the teachings and behavior of Jesus Christ.—1 Peter 2:21.
We believe that Jesus is the key to salvation, that “there is not another name under heaven that has been given among men by which we must get saved.”—Acts 4:12.
When people become Jehovah’s Witnesses, they are baptized in the name of Jesus.—Matthew 28:18, 19.
We offer our prayers in Jesus’ name.—John 15:16.
We believe that Jesus is the Head, or the one appointed to have authority, over every man.—1 Corinthians 11:3.

Source: JW.org—“Are Jehovah’s Witnesses Christians?”

Why are Muslims (Islam) not considered “Christian”?

A man joins the fold of Islam by honestly believing in and professing faith in the Oneness of Allah and the Prophethood of Muhammad.
Source: Islamweb—Islam: basic principles & characteristics-I

In conclusion, while all three denominations may have similar beliefs not all are followers of Jesus.

Upvoted +1. This is a remarkably Christian post. You've written an answer that stands out for its effort to respect the 9th commandment...which Christians ostensibly believe in.

@HoldToTheRod My Bible says the 9th commandment is not to give false testimony against your neighbour. Isn't there a difference between respecting the 9th commandment and "contending for the faith that was once for all entrusted to the saints" (Jude verse 3)? Godless men deny Jesus Christ as "our only sovereign and Lord" (Jude verse 4). Surely Christians must defend the faith especially when it is corrupted? Standing up for the faith may upset or offend others who claim they are not being respected.

@Lesley I don't take any issue with folks defending their faith and teaching what they believe is true. But if people have to misrepresent someone's faith in order to criticize it, it neither reflects well on their argument nor their commitment to the principles taught in their sacred texts. If I claim you believe X and you do not believe X, I would be bearing false witness against you, even if the audience loves my argument so much they won't fact check it.  Agarza is the only user who actually cited the words of the 3 faiths that are the focus of the question, and I applaud that approach.

It seems that those who disagree with the facts or don't like the answer once again downvote without commenting on why they are downvoting.

@agarza Sadly, this happens quite a lot here. Disagreeing with what someone believes is no basis for down-voting.

@HoldToTheRod, what does any of this have to do with "thou shalt not covet thy neighbor's wife"? You should be clearer about which numbering you're using, especially as you're apparently using a less common numbering.

Two people may meet together and identify themselves as 'Christian' and define, between themselves. what they mean by that identification.
They may invite a third to conform to what the two have agreed upon. Then more. And more.
The difference comes when Jesus Christ, Himself, in Person, is in the midst. And that it is He, Himself, who has done the gathering together ; through repentance, faith and a new birth.
Then - only then - is there a real 'Christian' gathering.
'Mimimal beliefs' will not arrive at that objective.
Only God can do it. It is salvation that results in sonship and worship, Ephesians 1:3.
I can call myself 'French' and learn a little bit of the language and identify as that which I wish to be. I can learn their politics and adopt their mannerisms.
But that does not change the fact that my origin, my birth, my parentage, are other than what I am  professing to be.
'Believing' beliefs, however minimal or however comprehensive, is not a guarantee of real faith..
Because 'faith works by love', Galatians 5:6. And 'we love him because he first loved us', 1 John 4:19. And to know that he loves me, means that I need to find him, know him and believe in him for myself.
Not as just a member of an external group called 'Christian'.
I need to find those who have the same birth as I, who share the same Spirit as I, who know the same Lord as do I.
Then, we are become One Body.
His Body.

"I can all myself 'French' and learn a little bit of the language and identify as that which I wish to be. I can learn their politics and adopt their mannerisms. But that does not change the fact that my origin, my birth, my parentage, are other than what I am professing to be." — I hope the "I can" refers to you at your current age. There are millions of us that immigrated at an early age and have not the slightest sense of identification with our birth country.

@RayButterworth I left my country of origin (Sotland) at the age of eighteen and left behind the religious organisation in which I had been brought up, and moved to England to follow the word of God and to gather with those of like mind and heart in England. Analogies and parables do not have to be exact or typical. They convey a concept. It is the concept that matters, not the practical detail.

Not to disagree with what this answer says about what defines a Christian, but as far as this question is concerned it is somewhat irrelevant. Muslims don't even claim to be Christian, so that fact by itself is enough to distinguish them from the other two groups. And I don't think anyone would argue that Jesus would claim a group that explicitly denies him.
¶And just to be clear, that's not my downvote; I tend to downvote badly written or argued items, not those that I simply disagree with. And in this case I do agree, but didn't upvote it because as I said, I think it misses the key issue.

Why are Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses considered Christian, but Muslims are not, when they believe the same regarding Jesus, the Trinity, and Bible?
The vast majority of Christian denominations do not consider Jehovah’s Witnesses or Mormons to be Christians at all. Mainstream Christianity is clearly Trinitarian.
Mormons and Jehovah’s Witnesses do not believe in the same theological definition of mainstream Christianity when it comes to the doctrine of the Most Holy Trinity.

Mormonism and Nicene Christianity (often called mainstream Christianity) have a complex theological, historical, and sociological relationship. Mormons express their doctrines using biblical terminology. They have similar views about the nature of Jesus Christ's atonement, bodily resurrection, and Second Coming as mainstream Christians. Nevertheless, most Mormons do not accept the doctrine of the Trinity as codified in the Nicene Creed of 325 and the Nicene-Constantinopolitan Creed of 381. Although Mormons consider the Protestant Bible to be holy scripture, they do not believe in biblical inerrancy. They have also adopted additional scriptures that they believe to have been divinely revealed to Joseph Smith, including the Book of Mormon, the Doctrine and Covenants, and the Pearl of Great Price. Mormons practice baptism and celebrate the sacrament of the Lord's Supper, but they also participate in other religious rituals. Mormons self-identify as Christians.
Mormons do not accept non-Mormon baptism and most non-Mormon Christians do not accept Mormon baptism. - Mormonism and Nicene Christianity

Islam as a religion, does not accept that Jesus is the Messiah, the word of God, who came from heaven. Neither do they accept what the Bible says about him. They believe Jesus was only a man, a prophet yes, but Muhammad is the last prophet. They deny the death and resurrection of Jesus and say he will come back as a follower of Muhammad
Neither Mormons, Jehovah’s Witnesses or Muslims believe in the Sacred Trinity in the same sense that Trinitarian denominations believe the Holy Trinity to be defined as. As such they have no valid baptisms and seeing that baptism is the initiation into the Christian Faith, they are not considered Christians.
Unitarians, Jehovah’s Witnesses and Mormons do not believe in Sacred Trinity and as such can not validly baptize someone.
An example if you wish (Catholic viewpoint):

“The words Father, Son and Holy Spirit, have for the Mormons a meaning totally different from the Christian meaning,” Ladaria wrote. “The differences are so great that one cannot even consider that this doctrine is a heresy which emerged out of a false understanding of the Christian doctrine. The teaching of the Mormons has a completely different matrix.”
In the Mormon understanding, baptism was begun by God with Adam, not by Christ. They deny the existence of original sin, and so do not act from the Catholic view that baptism remits both personal and original sin, Ladaria explained. If an LDS member renounces his or her faith or is excommunicated and later wants to return, they require a “re-baptism.”
For Christians, however, baptism is a unique event that can only take place once.
A minister of a Mormon baptism intends to do what the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints means by baptism, not what the Catholic Church means by it. - Are there baptisms that seem Christian, but aren’t?

Sometimes! In 2001, the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith said that baptism by the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints, informally known as Mormons, is not valid.
In the mind of the Catholic Church, Unitarians, Jehovah’s Witnesses and Mormons are considered a ecclesiastical community and not a Christian Church.
At first sight, it seems that Mormons baptize others in the name of the Trinity. But their intention is much different.
“Mormons hold that there is no real Trinity, no original sin, that Christ did not institute baptism,” Father Luis Ladaria, S.J., explained in an Aug. 1, 2001 article for L’Osservatore Romano. Ladaria would go on to head the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith under Pope Francis, who made him a cardinal in 2018.
Muslins are a non-Christian belief system altogether and follow the Quran or Koran as their Sacred book and hold Muhammad as God’s prophet which are not held to be so by Christian denominations.
The following may be of interest to some:

Would a person baptized by a Biblical Unitarian church be considered a Christian by the Catholic Church?

What is the basis that many mainstream Christian groups justify labeling groups like the Mormons and Jehovah Witnesses as Non-Christians?

What are the main differences between Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses?



Mormonism seems sort of similar to Eastern Orthodox, with their belief in the apotheosis of man and disbelief in original sin.  That being said, the belief that the trinity is just a collection of super beings that were created by yet higher beings is of course not at all within Christian orthodoxy.  On the other hand, the doctrine of the Trinity was not spelled out formally until hundreds of years after Jesus' time on earth, so a formally correct doctrine of the Trinity would not have been what Jesus' disciples believed.

So, one could maybe say that some aspects of Mormonism are more essential than others, and others are just human mistakes, like the Trinity being created, since logically you have to have an ultimate creator at some point to avoid an infinite regress.

Good edit to this answer. I see you have received a down-vote, however.

"The vast majority of Christian denominations do not consider Jehovah’s Witnesses or Mormons to be Christians at all."
— Isn't that simply a specific instance of the general case that most denominations consider themselves to be the true Christians and consider others to be misled because they hold different beliefs?
One could similarly say that most non-Catholics do not consider Catholics to be Christians (e.g. during the Reformation, the Church and the Pope were referred to as anti-Christ).
¶I'm not disagreeing, only pointing out that that statement isn't a very strong argument.

@RayButterworth Mainstream Christianity is Trinitarian.

Whether any or all of these are to be considered “Christian” comes down to how you define what it means to be Christian. Many claim that the Trinity is the defining belief of Christianity (despite it taking hundreds of years to develop after Christ) - and so they’d reject all of them as being properly Christian and instead just consider each to be different heresies.
From a more lenient, less orthodox perspective: both Mormonism and Jehovah’s Witnesses accept the canonical scriptures. They might not consider them inerrant and have competing interpretations and translations vs orthodoxy - but they don't fundamentally reject the scriptures. Jesus is the Son of God, the Jewish Messiah, who died for our sins and who ascended to God’s right hand as Lord. There is a judgment, etc.
Mormonism and Islam are similar in that they are based upon additional revelations from prophets after Christ. The nature of these revelations is distinct, however. Mormonism provides additional revelation- another testament- that (as I understand it) is supposed to be complementary to the standard Christian canon. Obviously, non-Mormons will contest that; but the intent is not to reform Christianity per se.
Islam, however, asserts that Christianity went far off the rails pretty much immediately and rejects many of the core elements of the NT. For example: they reject the idea that Jesus is the Son of God and I believe the Virgin Birth. They do accept him as the Jewish Messiah but reject that he died for our sins, etc. Since Islam outright rejects many of the core teachings of the Christian Canon - and does so not by competing interpretation, but by claiming the scriptures are simply corrupt, then they are indeed much further removed in practice from Orthodox Christianity than either of the other two sects.
That said, Islam does accept enough elements of Christianity that one might defend the notion that they are a non-orthodox variant of Christianity. Again, it all comes down to how you define “Christian.”

How can Islam be remotely described as a "non-orthodox variant of Christianity" when they deny the crucifixion, the resurrection and say Jesus will return as a follower of Muhammad to destroy any who refuse to submit to Allah?

@Lesley they maintain within their teachings that Jesus originally taught the same as what he taught; his tentative purpose being to restore the proper message asGod’s final prophet. If they believe this then, arguably, by following Islam they are following what Christ taught. Also they do in fact recognize him as the Jewish Messiah. I’m not recommending that we classify Islam as Christian - merely noting that it depends on how you define it. And for academic purposes you will find that they don’t necessarily use orthodoxy to determine if a given sect is Christian

Yes, this is along the lines of what I am getting at.  The disciples did not realize Jesus was God, but they did seem to think he was the messiah.  If that was sufficient for them to be Christians, i.e. followers of Jesus, then would that also qualify muslims who believe Jesus is the messiah?  Also, my understanding is Muslims accept the Torah and gospels as being alright, but think the epistles are corrupt, particularly those written by Paul.

@yters I’m pretty sure they reject the notion that Jesus is the Son of God (in any unique sense like the Virgin Birth) and that he died for our sins. If so then it’s not just Paul they contend with but the very Gospel itself

Muslims definitely reject Jesus being the Son of God, and the idea he died for our sins.  On the other hand, muslims believe in the virgin birth, and that Jesus was the messiah.  I've updated my question with quotes from the Quran.

@yters if they reject that Christ died for our sins then I can’t think of any books in the NT that they would find acceptable; save perhaps some of the very tiny epistles that may not explicitly reference his sacrifice (I’d have to double check)

Jesus dying for our sins is (very) strongly hinted at in the gospels, but it is only literally spelled out in the epistles.  Muslims may also think the objectionable parts in the gospels are corruptions.

@yters it’s pretty clearly laid out in each Gospel account that he was sent for the  explicit purpose of dying for our sins. For example, John 3:16-17 “For God so loved the world, that He gave His only Son, so that everyone who believes in Him will not perish, but have eternal life. For God did not send the Son into the world to judge the world, but so that the world might be saved through Him”

Yes, there are lots of verses in the gospels that make that conclusion pretty hard to escape.  It'd be interesting to know how muslims handle that.

@yters maybe ask on https://islam.stackexchange.com/

Amusingly, there's a significant gulf between what "Islam" teaches and what the Quran teaches. The idea that Scripture is corrupt is not found anywhere in the Quran; in fact, Christians are commanded by the Quran to obey 'the revelation given to them' (i.e. Scripture)!

@RyanPierceWilliams I'm not sure what you mean by "acceptable" in your comment six above this one.  We (Muslims) believe that the New Testament was written by a number of fallible humans, and therefore contains many errors - both factual and theological.  I believe many Christians believe something similar. I remember a Christian priest telling me once (rightly or wrongly) that Luke is the most accurate of the four canonical gospels; the implication being that the other three contain inaccuracies.  I guess it's possible to take guidance from a book without believing it's infallible.

@DawoodibnKareem all of the NT proclaims the Gospel; the salvific work of Christ and how through his blood we have redemption. If you have to dismiss what the scriptures teach as corrupt then you aren’t accepting them; you are cherry picking. I’m not a fundamentalist that I believe there’s no errors - but what you are doing is a fundamental rejection of all the NT, and without evidence

@RyanPierceWilliams Are you saying the New Testament wasn't written by a bunch of fallible humans? OK, so your view differs from that of the priest who talked to me; that's fine.  I DO find it bizarre that you're using the phrase "without evidence" to describe my view; while apparently asserting that the New Testament is not of human origin.  I feel that the burden of proof is with you, not with me.

@DawoodibnKareem I’m saying that if you want to argue that a given teaching was posthumously inserted - rather than what Christ and the early Christians taught from the beginning- then you need evidence. Tossing out teachings you don’t like based upon nothing more than the fact that it was written by men is not a valid argument

Oh, I have no doubt that the New Testament was almost entirely written by "early Christians", as you put it.  I just don't see why that would make it less prone to error than any other collection of books.

@DawoodibnKareem No one is saying that it isn’t susceptible to errors; it surely is. But if you are going to go around asserting this or that teaching is erroneous you need evidence to substantiate it. Blindly asserting that core teachings of the scripture are false simply because you don’t agree has no merit. Also, let us not forget that the Quran was also written by, transmitted by, and interpreted by fallible men as well.

So ... you just said that it's susceptible to errors.  Then you say that if I claim it's susceptible to errors, I need to provide evidence. So the rules are different for you?  You're simultaneously agreeing with me, and telling me I'm wrong. Either way, the New Testament contains some outlandish assertions - for example, that a man was crucified, then came back to life two days later. And there is absolutely no evidence that anything like that ever happened.  But in your reality, it's the people who DON'T believe the outlandish assertions that have to provide the evidence? That's a bit nuts.

@DawoodibnKareem no, you didn’t just say the scriptures are susceptible to errors - you are using the very generic fact that because, like everything else, scriptures can contain errors THEREFORE this particular thing MUST be in error. It’s a fallacious argument. And if you want to reject the scriptures because they speak of God and miracles and the like - then make sure you are consistent on that point and reject the Quran too. Can’t have prophets going around spreading the Word of God if you don’t believe in that sort of thing.

While the practical answers others have proposed are probably what you are really after, there is a more philosophical (metaphysical?) approach to your question that is much more difficult to unpack.  Your question hides an important presupposition about what constitutes "belief" and/or "faith".  Christians, myself included, will often cite John 3:16 as a nutshell synopsis of their faith, but doing so requires that the person citing the verse has a solid grip upon what they mean by "belief" and "love", among other things.
One can define belief as merely accepting certain unprovable facts as true, such as the existence of a point or a line in mathematics.  Even though the existence of these things is pretty much believed by everyone, most do not realize that everything we know about geometry and mathematics is based upon a few unprovable postulates that must be accepted without any supporting evidence.  I was a math major in college when I discovered this and it was amazing and confounding to me.  I thought math was pure logos with proofs built upon proofs, but I was wrong.  We cannot even begin to understand mathematics without presupposing a belief in facts that we cannot prove.  So that is one kind of belief or faith.
But there is also the idea that one can "believe" in someone or something else as a matter of admiration or approval.  Such as, I have faith in what you are doing or I believe in the American dream.
Jesus spoke a lot about faith being the most important thing a person should have if they seek to transcend their Earthly existence.  Jesus had little patience for those who did not exhibit absolute and unwavering faith in God, and this is also a theme that runs through every book of the Old Testament. But I often wonder exactly  what Jesus meant by faith in God and how do we know if we are doing it right.
For Christians, did Jesus demand that we believe in unprovable facts before we begin our life's journey?  Or did he expect us to merely believe in His existence 2000 years later?  Or are we to believe that Jesus was God; and was divinely conceived and became flesh only to ultimately be crucified and resurrected?  Maybe He meant that we are to remain "faithful" to God and put God at the center of our lives by making every decision, no matter how trivial or important, to be a matter of pleasing God?  As you can see, these things are not mutually exclusive nor are they inherently coupled together.  One can easily believe in the existence of Jesus and even in the resurrection but not keep God at the center of their lives. The converse is also true.  The fact that Jesus had not yet been crucified when He spoke of these things is strong evidence that Jesus was not talking about faith in His existence, but something deeper.
Clearly Muslims, Jews, Jehovah's Witnesses, LDS, and even Atheists along with any number of religions acknowledge that Jesus lived and was crucified.  The historical record supports these facts so it does not take any great sacrifice or courage to "believe" in these facts.  While probably not rigorously provable, they are generally accepted because of independent accounts and surviving records.
So faith must have more to do with belief as a world-view and not as a gap-filling fact-finding mission.  If it was just a matter of details like whether clerics should marry, whether the Eucharist undergoes transubstantiation versus consubstantiation, or whether baptism should be a conscious decision, most people accept that the Christian denominations that differ on these things are still Christians.  They might regard some of those beliefs as heretical or unscriptural, but not necessarily blasphemous.  Catholics and Lutherans have a long history of being at odds over a lot of these things, but only the most extreme zealots among them would suggest that the other is not Christian.
But the religious groups you mention have adopted radically different sets of beliefs than what I would consider mainstream Christian theology.  So even though they might all agree on the facts of Jesus' life, death, and resurrection, they do not agree upon what it all means to us as individuals or what exactly happened after the resurrection.  It is my understanding that Mormons and Jehovah's Witnesses consider themselves to be Christians, but I don't know if that is objectively true because it cannot be proven.  I can't even say for sure if objectivity is relevant in this context.
So your question is much deeper than it appears at first glance, and it requires deep soul-searching by those who practice and those who examine the motives of these religions.  In general, any religion that believes in the facts of Jesus' life, birth, and crucifixion can call itself Christian even though they interpret belief in a superficial way; while true and devoted Christianity requires much more of a believer.

Welcome to the site David. That's an interesting and well thought-out presentation, but one point that's important to flag up is this: The religion of Islam denies that Jesus Christ was crucified (consequently, neither was he resurrected). It denies that he is the Son of God. Those points alone mean that believing in the virgin Mary giving birth to him, and that he was a prophet of God, in no way means they could be considered Christians. The demons believe there is one God, they obeyed Jesus and knew he was crucified and resurrected, but that doesn't make them Christians! James 2:19

Very interesting answer.  Yes, you are right about all of math being an article of faith, and faith is consequently not a matter of collecting facts.  E.g. the devil believes all the right things about Jesus, but he doesn't have faith, and is not saved.
